# acer aspiroe one rviz segmentation fault

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I'm trying to run rviz in an acer aspire one with Intel GMA 3150 Graphics. I thinks that is the problem as I had no problem running rviz with computers with nvidia grafics.

When I try to run rviz I get this:

```
rosrun rviz rviz 
[ INFO] [1328201653.538028090]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1328201653.554674837]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1328201653.554843658]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1328201657.296367972]: Loading general config from [/home/turtlebot/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1328201657.318374992]: Loading display config from [/home/turtlebot/.rviz/display_config]
[ INFO] [1328201657.504465368]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
[ INFO] [1328201667.846179071]: Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
Segmentation fault
```

I'm not running it under a virtual machin.

Any idea of what can I do?

Thaks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12863/acer-aspiroe-one-rviz-segmentation-fault/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the steps here: [RViz](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting)

```
export OGRE_RTT_MODE=Copy
```

works for me most of the time in Electric

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on 2012-02-02**:
It worked! thanks!